# Passing parameter to explicit ruby block

Tags: ruby, parameters, block

Hello I'm trying to learn ruby blocks. But I have a trouble to get over this construction:

```
class SomeApp

  attr_accessor :load_listener

  def on_load(&block)
    @load_listener = block
  end

  def load(x)
    @load_listener.call(x) if @load_listener
  end

end

app = SomeApp.new
app.on_load { |x| puts 'on load #{x}'} 
app.load(5)
```

I don't understand why result of this code is **'on load #{x}'**, instead of **'on load 5'**
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using single quotes (`'`) instead of double quotes (`"`). String interpolation (`#{...}`) does only work with double quotes.

Change `puts 'on load #{x}'` to `puts "on load #{x}"`.